# AngularJS String-based JSON key value pairs

Tags: php, angularjs

I seem to be having some problems using JSON data to populate a select element in AngularJS.

The code:

```js
/* the API returns: {"id":3,"name":"Some Address"} */

app.service("addressService", function($http, $q) {
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   $http.get('/index.php/Pro/getAddresses').then(function(data) {
     deferred.resolve(data);
   });
   this.getCounties = function() {
     return deferred.promise;
   };
 });

 app.controller('homeController', function($scope, $http, addressService, $routeParams) {
   $scope.availableCounties = {};


   var promise = addressService.getCounties();
   promise.then(function(data) {
     $scope.availableCounties = data;
   });
 });
```

```html
<select name="sender_address_id" ng-model="sender_address_id" ng-options="county.id as county.name for county in availableCounties">

</select>
```

When I view the page, the select field remains unpopulated.  I do have control over the API as well.  If there is a better function or method to use than json_encode(), that would also solve the problem.

Edit, the console output shoes up as:

```
Object {data: Object, status: 200, headers: function, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}
config: Object
data: Object
  id: 3
  name: "Some Address"

  __proto__: Object

headers: function (c){a||(a=Xc(b));return c?(c=a[Q(c)],void 0===c&&(c=null),c):a}status: 200
statusText: "OK"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: is `{{availableCounties}}` empty if you log it in your view?

Comment: What does data actually look like when assigning to availableCounties in your promise? It probably needs to be an array of objects for the 'in availableCounties' to work on your ng-options declaration

Comment: Updated the question. :|

Comment: Urm ok, its not very readable, but I can already see that there are other named properties on the response like status and statusText, meaning just assigning 'data' wont work from your promise. The param passed in the then() is the entire response object, so it would be something like response.data to actually access the array of data for assigning to your scope variable.

Comment: Sorry.  I tried to make it as readable as I could.  Assigning availableCounties to data.data seemed to do the trick.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Greg, no worries, the $q doesn't know that the response body is important so that's why you need to access it through the .data notation.

I nice little overview here of success() vs then() - http://www.peterbe.com/plog/promises-with-$http

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the $http query into a service is useless here, since $http has a built-in promises system ([see documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)), and you don't add any logic (caching, data ordering, etc).

So, you can get rid of your service, and use this dead simple controller:

```
app.controller('homeController', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.availableCounties = [];

  $http.get('/index.php/Pro/getAddresses')
      .success(function (data) {
          $scope.availableCounties = data;
      })
      .error(function (error) {
          // Eventually do something when request fails
      });
});
```

**EDIT:**

As @kvetis states in comments, it is a good practice to keep http requests in one place. If you care about good practices, [here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xyhrmd2o/2/) demonstrating how to do this simply and cleanly.

Comment: I disagree with that. It would be a good practice to use a service if you're using the same API call on more places.

Comment: @kvetis Yep, I fully agree with you :) But then we have to simply return the $http request in the service, and not override its promises system. And here, I'm not fully sure that good practices are a priority ^^

Comment: Yes. It's true that you do not have to use $q and can simply return the result of `$http.get`